# Angular передать массив в php обработчик

Tags: http, typescript, angular

Имеется такой массив

```
Array
(
    [plan] => 629
    [series] => П-44К
    [roomQuantity] => 1
    [planMainImg] => /upload/iblock/ac5/p-44k-629-image.png
    [delivery] => 2 253 руб.
    [montage] => 9 459 руб.
    [garbage] => Бесплатно!
    [totalFull] => 56 218 руб.
    [thisUrl] => https://**********
    [backUrl] => /house/panel/p-44k/?BACK=629&STREET=Покровская улица&HOUSE=17к1
    [sale] => 
    [rooms] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Кухня 
                    [img] => /upload/roomimages/1256-2106-mask.png
                    [appertures] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [articul] => 2106_1855_73
                                    [img] => /upload/resize_cache/iblock/c2f/200_150_0d7a58ff99b324185ccb5ad5dfbdb5e85/ERKER2-W1-POL-W2-FPOR.png
                                    [name] => Эркерное окно из двух частей
                                    [system] => ***
                                    [price] => 14 837 руб.
                                    [totalPrice] => 20 860 руб.
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Подоконник ПВХ белый
                                                    [value] => 1 184 руб.
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Ручки Белая пластиковая стандарт (Россия)
                                                    [value] => 120 руб.
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Откосы белые (сендвич-панель)
                                                    [value] => 4086 руб.
                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Отливы наружние белые
                                                    [value] => 633 руб.
                                                )

                                            [4] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Механизм разгерметизации
                                                    [value] => 0 руб.
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Комната 1 
                    [img] => /upload/roomimages/2295-2107-mask.png
                    [appertures] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [articul] => 2107_16336_73
                                    [img] => /upload/resize_cache/iblock/02e/200_150_0d7a58ff99b324185ccb5ad5dfbdb5e85/BB2-W1-F10-BD1-POR.png
                                    [name] => Балконный блок с одностворчатым окном
                                    [system] => ***
                                    [price] => 15 725 руб.
                                    [totalPrice] => 23 646 руб.
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Подоконник ПВХ белый
                                                    [value] => 1 869 руб.
                                                )

                                            [1] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Ручки Белая пластиковая стандарт (Россия)
                                                    [value] => 120 руб.
                                                )

                                            [2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Откосы белые (сендвич-панель)
                                                    [value] => 5580 руб.
                                                )

                                            [3] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Отливы наружние белые
                                                    [value] => 352 руб.
                                                )

                                            [4] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Механизм разгерметизации
                                                    [value] => 0 руб.
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [FIRST] => Y
)
```

Пытаюсь передать в обработчик

```
const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            })
        };   

        return this.http.post(this.CONFIG.url + "/.ajax/addCalcForPrint.php" ,JSON.stringify(request),httpOptions);
```

На входе обработчика $_REQUEST = Array()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В php обработчике ответ необходимо было встречать таким образом:

```
$post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)
```